# How to have a VPS auto update on git pushes

Tags: python-3.x, git, ubuntu, vps, discord.py

So I have a python project on my VPS that I want to always be running, and when I push an update through git, it updates its files and restarts. How would I do this? (A discord.py rewrite bot exactly)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remote+deploy+hook

Answer (score 1):

You could add a GitHub webhook to a Discord channel and make your bot listen to it. If it detects a push message, make it run `git pull` and quit. Then, just run the bot in a loop with `while true; do python bot.py; done`.

Alternatively, write another script that will listen for HTTP requests from a GitHub webhook and kill the bot. You'll probably need to save the PID using bash.